# having trouble setting up python social auth to log in to facebook, facebook giving error that test user is not registered

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I am running my django app on a remote server.   When I try to log in to facebook using python-social-auth, I get the following error

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

I'm using a tutorial from [simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)

I've named the app that demonstrates the login "test_social" with a prefix "tsoc" as in /tsoc/login/facebook, etc.

I've managed to get it working on my localhost, I got it ssl certification using letsencrypt.org

it's just getting it to work remotely is very hard, I'm sure there is something I'm missing here.   I can't even use the test users I made to log in.

**If I am already logged in as a nomral user I get the following error:**

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

*screenshot of attempted sign-in while already logged in* [image: screenshot]

This happens if I'm signed in as the app administrator or if I'm signed in as an an accepted app developer.

**If I'm NOT already signed in to facebook and I try to use the log in I get the following error:**

> Error Accessing App - We're sorry but the application you are trying to use doesn't exist or has been disabled

*screenshot of attempted sign-in while NOT already logged in*
[image: screenshot]

here are some of the settings I already have on my facebook app

==========================================================

**Basic Settings**

(*note*: I changed the domain name, but the format is the same)

Settings->Basic  (top part)

[image: screenshot]

Settings->Basic (bottom part)

[image: screenshot]

==========================================================

**Facebook login settings**

Products->Facebook Login ->Settings

[image: Imgur]

==========================================================

** test user settings **
[image: Imgur]

==========================================================

**django settings**

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].append(
    'social_django.context_processors.backends')
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].append(
    'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect')

INSTALLED_APPS.append('social_django')
MIDDLEWARE.append('social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware')
```

(tsoc is the django app I'm using to login - as I said above it's based on a tutorial by [simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)

I've named the app that demonstrates the login "test_social" with a prefix "tsoc" as in /tsoc/login/facebook, etc.
)

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/tsoc/settings/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/tsoc/settings/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False


SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']

SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (  
'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = "XXXX"  # they exist, just hidden
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = "XXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your redirect URL defined in Facebook has `/oauth/` where your app is defined as `/tsoc/`. Other than that, the app is clearly defined as "in development" -- did you try to access it while logged into facebook as one of your test users?